# Unable to install USB Scanner Brother7420 on 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, scanner, brother

- Try to use [Document Scanner](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/simple-scan). I got an error about Scanner not found
- Downloaded driver from the [Brother website](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfc7420_all&os=128)
- `dpkg -i brscan2-0.2.5-1.amd64.deb`
- execute `brsaneconfig2 -d` and reply: `found USB scanner (vendor=0x04f9, product=0x0180) at libusb:003:002`
  But `scanimage -L` reply: `No scanners were identified.`
- on similar printer Brother publish some info about how to enable within the [FAQ](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=sg&lang=en&prod=dcp185c_eu_as&faqid=faq00100604_000) that implies to modify `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules`, but that file is not longer present on ubuntu 20.04, so I am not sure how to follow up.
- found an error of a missing usb library, but still have a problem:

`root@ubuntu20:/home/usuario# scanimage --test`

`scanimage: open of device brother2:bus2;dev1 failed: Invalid argument`

Comment: 1st, did you try to simply use the scanner with scanner software before you tried to install software?  Also your steps are unclear. You linked to a page with drivers that includes a `.deb` package which is inconsistent with what you've written above. If drivers are provided as a `.deb`, all you need to do is double click them (open them in the software center)

Comment: Thanks!. I have expand the question. I hope it is a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

### libusb-0.1-4 is missing:

```
root@ubuntu20:~# SANE_DEBUG_DLL=3 scanimage -L
    [23:30:54.437751] [dll] load: searching backend `brother2' in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane:/usr/lib/sane:/usr/lib64/sane'
    [23:30:54.437770] [dll] load: dlopen()ing `/usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother2.so.1'
    [23:30:54.437995] [dll] load: dlopen() failed (libusb-0.1.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

so libusb-0.1-4 is missing: `apt-get install libusb-0.1-4`

```
root@ubuntu20:~# scanimage -L
device `brother2:bus2;dev1' is a Brother MFC-7420 USB scanner
```